# Does there exist a real normal matrix that's not symmetric, antisymmetric, orthogonal, and has distinct singular eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, svd, singular-values

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2046163/does-there-exist-a-normal-matrix-which-is-not-diagonal-nor-hermitian-nor-unitar) points out a matrix on Wikipedia that is real, normal, and neither symmetric, antisymmetric, or orthogonal. However, its singular values are 2, 1, 1. Is there one that has distinct singular values?

Answer (score 4):

No, there is not any such matrix.

- If a real normal matrix has a real spectrum, it is orthogonally diagonalisable and hence symmetric.
- If a real normal matrix has a non-real eigenvalue $\lambda$, then $\bar\lambda$ is also an eigenvalue of this matrix, because non-real eigenvalues of a real matrix must occur in conjugate pairs. But then $|\lambda|$ will be a repeated singular value, because the singular values of a normal matrix are the moduli of the eigenvalues.